# Grep F Parameter Not Complete Match

Tags: grep, string

I'm trying to use the `-F` parameter on a `grep` to match a PHP variable. When I run:

```
grep -F "$_SESSION['index']" -ri .
```

though it is only matching:

```
['index']
```

How can I get it to also match the `$_SESSION`? Is the `$_SESSION` being read as a non-existent environment variable and the `grep` is read as `['index']`? I thought the `-F` would make it read as plain text, maybe that just turns off regex behavior though.

If that is the behavior how can I do this? I can't use single quotes for the encapsulation because the PHP uses single for its; escaping fails in shell:

```
grep -F '$_SESSION[\'index\']' -ri .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -F` does not avoid shell parsing.

Within double quotes, escape the dollar sign:

```
grep -F "\$_SESSION['index']" -ri .
```

---

Single quotes can contain anything except for other single quotes – there is no escape character – however, the quoted string can be concatenated with escaped quotes:

```
grep -F '$_SESSION['\''index'\'']' -ri .
```

Comment: Thanks. hadn't thought of escaping the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also jam several differently quoted sections together to make one word. In this instance:

```
grep -F '$_SESSION'"['index']" -ri .
```